# Add images into gallery

Tags: android, gallery

I need to pick an image from my mobile gallery, then add it to my app's horizontally scrollable gallery. I'm trying to use this:

```
Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
```

But `Gallery` is deprecated. What is the best solution for this? Maybe a collection of `imageViews`?

Comment: See here: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html

Comment: shortened and simplified the question